# ASP.NET MVC3 C# - edit functionality in detail view of a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a forum.  I'm trying to have the functionality of 'post edit' in 'thread details'

I have the standard OTB Thread index view, and when you click on 'details'  it shows the OTB Thread details, I have added a foreach to display the posts relating to that thread underneath.

I'm now struggling with adding/allowing the posts that are displayed underneath to be edited.  Specifically show/hide.

In context, all posts are 'hidden' until an administrator clicks a button to 'show' a post, and vice versa

Thread Controller:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {

        tb_SH_Forum_Threads tb_sh_forum_threads = db.tb_SH_Forum_Threads.Single(t =>   t.Thread_ID == id);
        ViewBag.Private_ID = new SelectList(db.tb_SH_Forum_PrivateDesc, "Private_ID", "Private_Desc");
        return View(tb_sh_forum_threads);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Shareholder_Forum.Models.tb_SH_Forum_Threads

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>tb_SH_Forum_Threads</legend>

<div class="display-label">Thread_Title</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Thread_Title)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Thread_Details</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Thread_Details)
</div>

<div class="display-label">tb_SH_Forum_Categories</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tb_SH_Forum_Categories.Category_Description)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Thread_Date</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Thread_Date)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Replies</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Replies)
</div>
</fieldset>

@foreach
(var post in Model.tb_SH_Forum_Posts.Where(w => w.Private_ID == 1).OrderBy(o =>     o.Post_Date))
{

        <div class ="post">
<fieldset>
        <p class="post_details">At @post.Post_Date By @(post.Anon == true ? "Anonymous"    : post.Username)          
        </p>
        @post.Post_Desc

</fieldset>
        </div>}

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")|

</p>
```

I think I need to use RenderAction and/or Partial views, but I don't understand.  Any advice, or point me in the right direction where I can learn about this.

As always, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain I understand what you want, but here's how you could do what I think you're asking.

```
@foreach (var post in Model.tb_SH_Forum_Posts.Where(w => w.Private_ID == 1).OrderBy(o =>     o.Post_Date))
{
    if(post.IsEditable) //however you're determining if they can edit the post. Alternatively display both this and the else and use javascript to toggle which one you show
    {
         ///...Your old view post code
    }
    else
    {
       @Html.RenderPartial("EditPost", new {postdata = post})
    }
 }
```

Make a model

```
public class PostDataViewModel
{
     public Post PostData
     {
        get;
        set;
     }
}
```

EditPost.cshtml

```
 @model PostDataViewModel

 // The editable form and button to submit to SaveForumPost action
```

Save it with

```
public virtual ActionResult SaveForumPost(PostaDavaViewModel model)
{
   //... save edits
   // either return a redirect to Detail, or if you don't want to refresh the page call this with ajax
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply.  I get a bit lost at the model part (because I have to make apps DB first and I have zero experience with code models) but the rest makes sense!

Comment: No problem. The models just supposed to be whatever info is needed to identify and edit your post from within the PartialView. I don't know what you named your classes so I just called it Post. If any of its unclear just say which part.